# Div scrolling but not stopping at the top of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fixed

I have been working on setting up a simple action where when a page is long, a div starts in the centre of the screen and when a user scrolls further down the screen, the div moves with the rest of the content but stops at the top while the rest of the content can continue.

I have managed to (with a lot of help going through here and searching) get as far as having the div scroll, but it won't stop at the top of the screen and disappears off with the rest of the content.

I have been fiddling with different bits for the past couple of hours but now I'm just beyond my current understanding and just haven't got a clue where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

What I'm using as the js is:

```
var StickyElement = function(node){
var doc = $(document), 
  fixed = false,
  content = node.find('#logo');

var onScroll = function(e){
var docTop = doc.scrollTop(),
    anchorTop = anchor.offset().top;

console.log('scroll', docTop, anchorTop);
if(docTop > anchorTop){
  if(!fixed){
    anchor.height(content.outerHeight());
    content.addClass('stuck');        
    fixed = true;
  }
}  else   {
  if(fixed){
    anchor.height(0);
    content.removeClass('stuck'); 
    fixed = false;
  }
}
};

  $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
};
```

The codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/embvRL

Comment: Check if you are adding correctly your classes, I did a small fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/edkLk1k9/1/. Just to give you an idea of how can works too.

Comment: Thank you for your example. This makes much more sense than the code I was working with, and I kind of understand it except that I am unable to get it working outside of jsfiddle. I copied it verbatim with no luck. I also tried it in codepen and it still didn't work. I'm baffled to say the least!

Comment: Mmm.. I'm baffled too, I have tested the solution given by @Mia Marks and it works perfectly. Have you tried to see the browser console? maybe there are some libraries that you're not icluding like jQuery, or some others are in conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does something like this work for you?

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/4Ls8L6a6/)**

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.main p {
   margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.centered_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 240px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0 0 0 -120px;
}

.fixedPos {
    position:fixed !important;  
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="centered_text">
    centered
</div>    
<div class="main">
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var originalLogoPosition = $('.centered_text').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var logo = $('.centered_text');
    var pos = logo.offset();
    var posScrollTop = pos.top;   

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > posScrollTop) {
     logo.addClass('fixedPos');   
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < originalLogoPosition) {
     logo.removeClass('fixedPos');     
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As with Diego, thank you for your reply and the example. But again, I am unable to get this working outside of jsfiddle. Are these real life examples that can be used outside of jsfiddle? As I cannot get these to work even by using alternatives to jsfiddle (ex. codepen).

Comment: I edited my answer and included the entire html page code for you to look at - it works in real life yes. :)

Comment: Thank you! That does work with it in one file. I've tried taking the javascript out into a separate file and then referencing it, but it stops working so for the time being I'll leave it where it is I think. Thank you @Diego and Mia

Comment: are you including jquery library and where are you putting the script?  If you are putting the js reference below the jquery it should work - if you are using document.ready and including it somewhere else that may be your issue

Comment: It works! I think it must have been a cache issue on my browser and was still loading the old code. But it's all working now with a separate file. Thank you for your help. Cudos :-)